How to change date to day/month/year

I want the form to show day/month/year instead of how it is showing now.
This is how it looks like in html please help.
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
  <input asp-for="Input.FirstDay" type="date" class="form-control" aria-required="true" />
  <label asp-for="Input.FirstDay">Första dagen</label>
  <!--  <span asp-validation-for="Input.FullName" class="text-danger"></span>  -->
</div>

I am using DateOnly in C#.
Someone know how to fix it?

Why do you want this? Are you sure there's a problem to fix to begin with? The input type="date" HTML element uses the end user's locale to format dates. The actual value though is always ISO8601 ie YYYY-MM-DD which is automatically mapped to .NET date types

As the Mozilla site explains, The displayed date format will differ from the actual value — the displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's browser, but the parsed value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd.

You cannot (currently) change the display format used by <input type="date"> there's simply nothing in the spec and browsers use the client's OS date format.

The format displayed in an  is determined by the browser and generally follows the user's local settings.

Thx for replies. I Have another question with the form. When i open the calendar that the form has it starts with showing sunday to saturday instead of how i want it monday to sunday.  Is it possible to change that?

No, and if you check the link to the docs you'll see the HTML date picker is rather restricted. If you want something that isn't available you'll have to use a third-party component. Those hide or replace the input type='date' field and use Javascript to display the format and pickers you want. jQuery UI's Datepicker for example is one of the oldest pickers that support custom formats and customization
